# Скопировать найденный список файлов

Tags: linux, bash

Найти в домашней папке все файлы, начианющиеся с букв "a" по "z" и скопировать их в папку temp в домашнем "каталоге".

Как найти понятно: `find -name "[a-z]*"`, а как именно выбранные файлы скопировать в папку?

Comment: А зачем тут find, просто встроенные функции шелла не подойдут? `cp [a-z]* ~/temp`

Comment: `find -name "[a-z]*" -exec cp {} ~/temp/ \;` но комментарий выше более рационален в данном случае

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, только я бы добавил `mkdir ~/temp| cp [a-z]* ~/temp` ведь директории еще не существует

Comment: @polsok тогда уж лучше `mkdir ~/temp && cp [a-z]* $_` в случае если возникнет ошибка вторая команда не запустится, ну и имя каталога указывается только при создании. Надо потестить конечно, но по идее должно сработать

Comment: А на сообщения от cp про невозможность скопировать папку забиваем? Как минимум temp в этот список тоже попадёт

Comment: @andreymal, `find` нужен, чтобы тип файла выбрать правильно. Автору, не слушайте дурных советов :)

Comment: @0andriy ну так уточните что что бы тип файла выбрать правильно в `find` нужно дописать `-type f`, а то будут скопированы не только файлы, но и каталоги.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже думал над этим вопросом, как сразу все сделать одной строкой, отличная подсказка на счет Copy. Но как верно заметили, могут быть папки при копировании помимо файлов. Я так думаю идеальный вариант решения будет:

```
mkdir ~/temp && cp [a-z]*.* ~/temp
```